# model does not contain a public instance definition for 'OnlineUserModel'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.OnlineUserModel> 

<div class="form-group online">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)  <br />
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/OnlineUsers",
```

MODEL :

```cs
public class OnlineUserModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
                   
    public OnlineUserModel(DataRow rs)
    {    
        if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(rs["UserName"])) this.UserName = (string)rs["UserName"];
        if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(rs["UserID"])) this.UserID = (string)rs["UserID"];    
    }    
        
    public static List<OnlineUserModel> OnlineUsersList()
    {
        List <OnlineUserModel> user = new List<OnlineUserModel>();
        DataTable resultTable = Globals.CommonData.RetrieveOnlineUsers();
        if (resultTable != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow rs in resultTable.Rows)
            {
                user.Add(new OnlineUserModel(rs));
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult  OnlineUsers()
{
    return Json(Project.Models.OnlineUserModel.OnlineUsersList());
}
```

I did the same exact way on my other project and it is working fine but this one keeps giving me error and I need help in figuring it out. Probably an obvious one for the experienced contributor here but not for me. Thank you, Pls point me to the right direction.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of your OnlineUserModel?

Comment: @GideonBotha Sir I did post all my model code. Thank you

Comment: your model has constructor that requires DataRow, in your code i don't see where you pass DataRow into constructor, either add default constructor without DataRow param or fix your code to pass DataRow